# How do I get a python regular expression to return all text not matching?

Tags: python, regex, replace

So, I am successfully matching and extracting some special tagged text using the following regular expression:

```
theString = u"Var 1 value: %%v:123453%%, Var 2 value: %%v:984561%%, Var 3 value: %%v:123456%%"
p = re.compile("\%%v:([0-9]*)%%")
theIds = p.findall(theString)
```

That returns

```
[u'123453', u'984561', u'123456']
```

which is exactly what I need. Next, I need to replace those with some looked up value, so what I'd like to get next is this:

```
[u'Var 1 value: ', u', Var 2 value: ', u', Var 3 value: ']
```

So that I can glue those strings together with the looked up values from the first list, resulting in a string that looks something like this:

u"Var 1 value: Some Value, Var 2 value: 837, Var 3 value: more stuff"

Or, if there's a better way to do the replacement I'm all ears.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Edit your question. See the little edit button right below the little blue tag boxes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a replacement function to insert arbitrary substitutions. See the [`re.sub`](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html#re.sub) documentation for how the function works. Here is an example:

```
values = {
    u'123453': u'Some Value',
    u'984561': u'837',
    u'123456': u'more stuff',
}

def insertLookup(matchobj):
    return values[matchobj.group(1)]

theString = u"Var 1 value: %%v:123453%%, Var 2 value: %%v:984561%%, Var 3 value: %%v:123456%%"
p = re.compile("\%%v:([0-9]*)%%")
newString = p.sub(insertLookup, theString)

print newString
u"Var 1 value: Some Value, Var 2 value: 837, Var 3 value: more stuff"
```

The `insertLookup` function will be called for each match, and is passed a [MatchObject](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html#match-objects). We then use the matched value (`u'123453'`, etc.) to look up the replacement value, which then is inserted into `newString` instead of the matched string.

Comment: @Andrew: it's an example that'll run in one go. The OP can use a different lookup method too.

Comment: Sorry, I misread the post thinking that he was replacing on index, not values.

Comment: I've updated the answer to include better values to insert (matching the OP) and what the output will look like.

Answer (score 2):

How about the following?

```
theString = u"Var 1 value: %%v:123453%%, Var 2 value: %%v:984561%%, Var 3 value: %%v:123456%%"
p = re.compile("\%%v:([0-9]*)%%")
replacements = ["Some Value", "837", "more stuff"]
newString = p.sub(lambda m: replacements.pop(0), theString)
```

You can provide a function to `re.sub()`, in this case the function takes the first item from a `replacements` list and substitutes it for the match.

**edit**: I misread the question and missed that you want to look up the replacement values based on the initial values, you probably want something like [Martijn's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5872299/how-do-i-get-a-python-regular-expression-to-return-all-text-not-matching/5872450#5872450) for your replacement.  As far as returning all text not matching, you can remove the group in your regex and then use `re.split()`:

```
>>> theString = u"Var 1 value: %%v:123453%%, Var 2 value: %%v:984561%%, Var 3 value: %%v:123456%%"
>>> p = re.compile("%%v:[0-9]*%%")
>>> p.split(theString)
[u'Var 1 value: ', u', Var 2 value: ', u', Var 3 value: ', u'']
```

Comment: Martijn's solution will probably work, but thanks for the split pointer - always nice to learn new methods.

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just `split(', ')` the string and work with the individual pieces?

A naive solution of mine would be something like this:

```
theString = u"Var 1 value: %%v:123453%%, Var 2 value: %%v:984561%%, Var 3 value: %%v:123456%%"

for chunk in theString.split(', '):
  temp = str(chunk)

  p = re.compile("\%%v:([0-9]*)%%")
  theIds = p.findall(theString)

  theOpposite = temp.replace(theIds[0])
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of "p.findall" use "p.sub".